# Implementing power for evaluating an expression in C++ Expression Templates

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I have to evaluate an expression of the format x power n + 1.I have overloaded +,-,*,/ using the following format

```
template<class L,class R>
Expr<L,R,plus<double> > operator+(const L l,const R r){
return Expr<L,R,plus<double> >(l,r);
};
```

How do I do the same for powers?

My program can evaluate an expression of type x+1+2x or any without powers.i want to be able to evaluate one with powers like (2xpower2)+2 or so where the value of x is a variable.

Comment: There is no 'power' operator in C++, just the `pow()` free function from <cmath>. You can overload that like any other function.

Comment: I mean my coursework says implement addition,subtraction,multiplication,division,integration,differentiation and exponentiation.it is only the exponentiation that i am stuck with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a template specializtion for x^0 that returns 1.

Define a template for the general case (i.e. x^y) that returns `x * pow<x, y-1>`

Comment: Note that the `^` operator doesn't have the precedence rules you'd expect for exponentiation. Using it as a "power" operator is therefore not recommended.

Comment: I agree with you pmjordan.since I dont want to use ^ which is the Bit Or operator.

Comment: Wny not define the general case to use squaring instead? A-la STL `power()`?

Comment: And the template should evaluate any power,whether raised to 2 ,3,or 20

Comment: @coderboy see Notes at http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/power.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring - if you're raising to integer power, it's a O(log n) operation.

Comment: I created a new template and overloaded the ^ operator as that seemed the easiest option